# Максимальное количество параметров

Tags: c++, c, функции, шаблоны-с++, стандарт

Какое максимальное количество параметров может иметь функция?

А каково максимально возможное количество шаблонных параметров?

Comment: Теоретически или практически?

Comment: @Harry и то и то интересно, если теория от практики отличается =-)

Comment: Теоретически - до бесконечности :), а практически... Ну, 1024 только что на VC++ 2019 проверил - компилирует... Конечно, какие-то внутренние ограничения там есть, но вряд ли вы с ними в реальной программе столкнетесь.

Comment: согласно исследованиям (а такие проводились) функция должна иметь не более 7 (+2) параметров - если больше, то человеку труднее за ними уследить в функции. Почитайте МакКонела - он хорошо писал об этом

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch можно ссылку на исследование? Интересно почитать

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Это психологическое ограничение, а не техническое...

Comment: @Harry все верно, но код, все-таки, все еще пишут люди, а не машины

Comment: @Варфаламей ну я же вам написал "почитайте МакКонела"

Comment: Ага, на VC++2019 нарвался на предел компилятора: объявление функции не должно превышать 64 Кбайта...

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Ну, далеко не весь :) Или вы считаете, что этот код с 25000 параметров у функции, который я компилятору подсунул, я руками писал?...

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch вот это? Совершенный код. Мастер-класс / Пер. с англ. — М. : Издательско-торговый дом «Русская Редакция» ; СПб.: Питер, 2005. — 896 стр.: ил. ISBN 5-7502-0064-7 ISBN 5-469-00822-3

Comment: @Harry а он делает что-то полезное?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Конечно - позволяет ответить на поставленный вопрос :) Как я понимаю, lex, yacc и иже с ними с вашей точки зрения тоже генерируют исключительно бесполезный код?

Comment: @Harry вот только не опускайтесь до передергиваний, ок? Я ничего не говерил ни про бесполезность вашего кода, ни тем более про `yacc` - перечитайте что я писал и убедись в этом. Я лишь сомневаюсь в применимость и полезности генерирования функций на с++ с огромным количеством параметров - вот и все. Генерация ради генерации меня как-то не сильно убеждает в обратном. Но раз уж вы тут затронули yacc и другие генераторы, то приведите хоть один пример из распрастраненных генераторов кода, где генерируются функции с огромным количеством параметров

Comment: @Варфаламей Огромная просьба - уточните свой вопрос: он касается **психологических** или **технических** ограничений?

Comment: с точки зрения удобства сопровождения кода кол-во параметров функции должно стремиться к минимуму, а если параметров много то это скорее всего какие то сущности которые можно связать в один класс, много флагов можно передавать через битовые поля, также кортежи можно рассмотреть в каких-то случаях

Comment: @Варфаламей да, это она

Comment: Забавно, что Варфоломей так и не дождался ответа, исчез через 20 минут после заданного вопроса и больше не появлялся... Похоже, ответ на вопрос его не слишком-то и интересовал :)

Answer (score 13):

Смотрим приложение B к стандарту C++20 - **Implementation quantities**.

В нем указаны *минимальные* значения, которым должны (желательно) отвечать компиляторы.

> (2.11) — Parameters in one function definition (9.5.1) [256].

Т.е., в соответствии со стандартом компилятор должен поддерживать функции с не менее чем 256 параметрами. Ограничений сверху стандарт не накладывает...

О шаблонах там же сказано

> (2.40) — Template parameters in a template declaration (13.2) [1024].

Тут ограничение снизу в 4 раза больше :)

Если интересно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/implimits